# How to type chained calls to a Typescript object

Tags: typescript

I need to create a translation system where the elements are in a Typescript object like this:

```js
const fr: AppMessages = {
  builder: {
    actionButtons: {
      preview: 'Visualisation',
      ...
    },
  },
};
```

So I typed the object with this type:

```js
interface AppMessages extends Record<string, string | AppMessages> {}
```

But when I want to read a subkey :

```js
const test: string = fr.builder.actionsButton.preview;
```

Typescript shows me this error: *TS2339: Property 'actionsButton' does not exist on type 'string | AppMessages'.   Property 'actionsButton' does not exist on type 'string'.*

Is it possible to make it tell me that the intermediate key returns a specific type, in this case that `builder` returns `AppMessages` and not `string`, or is it my type that I need to write differently?

Thx for your responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your entire messages object is statically declared, you can just use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const fr  = {
  builder: {
    actionButtons: {
      preview: 'Visualisation'
    },
  },
} as const;

const t = fr.builder.actionButtons.preview;
```

Comment: That's a good thought, this does look like static data.

Comment: So the solution is not to type the starting object, because by using the const assertion we don't type the object, we just tell it that it is read-only?

Comment: It's a way of saying that the entire object is narrowly typed as-declared, and that it cannot be changed.

Comment: @Robby Cornelissen Good! I didn't know this feature! Thanks a lot!